# Redis failure causing Login and Signup problem in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, redis, centos

- My Website is in Laravel 5.6
- It is hosted on AWS > EC2, CentOS > using Nginx. Attached is server architecture

[image]

- PHP version 7.1
- Attached you can server architecture. It is autos calling server.
- Also I have attached Redis log https://prnt.sc/qdv3is and https://prnt.sc/qdv539

Now problem is: Daily once, sometimes twice or thrice, We get Redis error probably memory full but not sure you can see attached server logs. Right now, we restart redis as a temporary solution to it. When this error comes then on Laravel side login, signup etc everything stops working and I see following error in Laravel logs.

local.ERROR: MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots, but is currently not able to persist on disk. Commands that may modify the data set are disabled. Please check Redis logs for details about the error. {"exception":"[object] (Predis\Response\ServerException(code: 0): MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots, but is currently not able to persist on disk. Commands that may modify the data set are disabled. Please check Redis logs for details about the error. at /var/www/html/vendor/predis/predis/src/Client.php:370)

As a solution, I have disabled stop on background save but it did not work.

What can be reason behind it?

Answer (score 0):

since Redis is configured as cache, there is no need to enable writes

```
$ redis-cli
> config set stop-writes-on-bgsave-error no
```

also  make sure to set the Linux kernel overcommit memory setting to 1. Add `vm.overcommit_memory = 1` to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command `sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1` for this to take effect immediately. https://redis.io/topics/admin